# How can I make a function implement the internals of a custom instance of Show. Haskell

Tags: haskell

I wrote this data type:

```
data Poly = Lit Integer |
            Var |
            Add Poly Poly |
            Mul Poly Poly
```

I'd like to also write a function printPoly for it, that takes a Poly expression and returns it converted to string. This can be implemented by just creating a custom instance of show for data type Poly like so:

```
instance Show Poly where
   show (Lit x)   = show x
   show (Var)     = "x"
   show (Add x y) = (show x) ++ " + " ++ (show y)
   show (Mul x y) = (show x) ++ "*" ++ (show y)
```

Now if I pass an expression like

```
main = do
print (Add (Lit 1) $ Add (Var) $ Mul (Var) $ Mul Var Var)
```

It returns `1 + x + x*x*x`. Which is what I want. However, I want this done from a function printPoly, like so:

```
printPoly::Poly->String
printPoly (Lit x) = show x
printPoly (Var) = "x"
printPoly (Add x y) = (show x) ++ " + " ++ (show y)
printPoly (Mul x y) = (show x) ++ "*" ++ (show y)
```

Where am I wrong in the way I wrote this function?

Comment: Change `show` to `printPoly` in the recursive cases of `printPoly`.

Comment: @RumenHristov Why exactly did you revert my edit which corrected your incorrect markdown from something rendering as `1 + x + xxx` to make it say `1 + x + x*x*x`?  Do you realize that asterisks without code markup will italicize the center x?

Comment: I did not revert it. I tried to accept it.

Comment: @user2407038 Why don't you write your comment as an answer, so I can accept it as one? It most definitely works.

Comment: @RumenHristov Hmmm....well, [looks like rollback to revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26591372/revisions) in the history.

Comment: @HostileFork Just edit it again man. I won't touch it.

Comment: @RumenHristov Not a big deal, just found it strange to have it reverted.  :-)

Comment: @RumenHristov I just finished some edits on the community wiki Zeta started on your previous question, it should give you a good picture of showing expressions like this in a pretty fashion.

Comment: @bheklilr Marvelous. I will review it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as-asked, this is what you want to do.

```
printPoly :: Poly -> String
printPoly (Lit x) = show x
printPoly (Var) = "x"
printPoly (Add x y) = (printPoly x) ++ " + " ++ (printPoly y)
printPoly (Mul x y) = (printPoly x) ++ "*" ++ (printPoly y)

instance Show Poly where
   show = printPoly
```

However, this has some obvious problems. Consider `print (Mul (Lit 2) $ Add Var Var)`. This would print `2*x + x`, which when following precedence rules is clearly not what was intended.

```
printPoly :: Poly -> String
printPoly (Lit x) = show x
printPoly (Var) = "x"
printPoly (Add x y) = (b x $ printPoly x) ++ " + " ++ (b y $ printPoly y)
  where b (Add _ _) p = "(" ++ p ++ ")"
        b _         p = p
printPoly (Mul x y) = (b x $ printPoly x) ++ " * " ++ (b y $ printPoly y)
  where b (Mul _ _) p = "(" ++ p ++ ")"
        b _         p = p
```

This will print out `2 * (x + x)` which is the correct interpretation of the given AST. Further, you could simplify the whole thing a bit by using `printf` from `Text.Printf`

```
printPoly :: Poly -> String
printPoly (Lit x) = show x
printPoly (Var) = "x"
printPoly (Add x y) = printf "%s + %s" (b x $ printPoly x) (b y $ printPoly y)
  where b (Add _ _) = printf "(%s)"
        b _         = id
printPoly (Mul x y) = printf "%s * %s" (b x $ printPoly x) (b y $ printPoly y)
  where b (Mul _ _) = printf "(%s)"
        b _         = id
```

Of course, this is still doing a lot of linked-list traversal, munging together strings so it won't be very fast, but at least it's correct ;)